# Unable to delete folder in linux with special character

Tags: linux, command

I have a folder which is:

```
/var/www/xxx/html/'.
```

It was created accidentally. I try to delete it but it comes up,

> No such files or directory

I have tired

```
rm -f /var/www/xxx/html/'.

rm -f "/var/www/xxx/html/'."

rm -f /var/www/xxx/html/*'*.
```

It is because of the `'`.

I have been looking around for a few hours but no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /var/www/xxx/html
rm -rf \'.
```

worked for me.

Comment: Hmmmm. I am going to investigate more.

Comment: Every I try to change the user of the folder, it says chown: cannot access `.\nsudo chown    - I have noticed that is change ' for '' < Only  one , Stackoverflow is trying to format the coding.

Comment: Ok, what's your problem? To remove a directory or to change ownership?

Comment: Both. I cannot remove the dir unless I change the ownership.

Comment: This is strange. I still get permission denied, I can create folder in the folder and delete them...

Comment: if you want to delete a directory entry, you need the permissions in that directory to do so. So please check the permissions of `/var/www/xxx/html`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

rmdir /var/www/xxx/html/\'